# Добавить в проект conscrypt

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Хочу в android проект добавить свой JCE провайдер, как за основу хочу использовать Conscrypt. Объясните как добавить в проект [Conscrypt](https://conscrypt.org/). Пробую создать android проект и в не него добавляю все файлы из репозитория, но Android Studio ругается на все что только можно. Сначало ругалась на импорты, я их исправил. Теперь не могу скомпилировать из-за того что там не хватает класса NativeConstants. Облазил весь инет нигде его не нашёл, на репозитории тоже нет.

Comment: пробовали добавить jar файл как библиотеку

Comment: мне нужны именно исходные файлы т.к. я хочу изменить и дополнить реализацию.

Comment: свой JCE провайдер вы на чем делали? может добавить свой JCE провайдер как библиотеку.

Comment: Вплане на чем я делал? На Java я пишу. Почему же, если я создам класс например MyJSSE extends Provider. Положу туда свои реализации алгоритмов и прочего. Как например сделано тут https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/master/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLProvider.java Получиться уже новый JCE провайдер, мой.